# DynamoDB - identity I will never query against

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have been reading about DynamoDB hash, range keys and indices. My use case is simple, but I'm already confused.

I want to store 3 values:

- event ID
- event timestamp
- article ID

Essentially, this means an article ID was accessed on the timestamp. Event ID uniquely identifies the event, and should allow for now duplicates.

I guess this suggests event ID should be my primary key?

But I will always query using article ID and timestamp.

My only idea is event ID = primary key with article ID and timestamp being secondary indices. But is that optimal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html) can be setup on article Id & timestamp and queries performed against the created index for better read performance.

Comment: Thanks. So primary key on Event ID, and one GSI on the other two columns?

Comment: That's the way to go.